# Scheduling AirfFlow DAG job

Tags: airflow

I have written a AirFlow DAG as below -

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2016, 7, 5),
    'email': ['airflow@airflow.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=30),
    # 'queue': 'bash_queue',
    # 'pool': 'backfill',
    # 'priority_weight': 10,
    # 'end_date': datetime(2016, 1, 1),
}

dag = DAG(
    'test-air', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='*/2 * * * *')
.................
.................
{{Tasks}}
```

As per above config, Job should run every even minute. But instead it shows below output

```
airflow scheduler -d test-air
[2016-07-05 15:24:02,168] {jobs.py:574} INFO - Prioritizing 0 queued jobs
[2016-07-05 15:24:02,177] {jobs.py:726} INFO - Starting 0 scheduler jobs
[2016-07-05 15:24:02,177] {jobs.py:741} INFO - Done queuing tasks, calling the executor's heartbeat
[2016-07-05 15:24:02,177] {jobs.py:744} INFO - Loop took: 0.012636 seconds
[2016-07-05 15:24:02,256] {models.py:305} INFO - Finding 'running' jobs without a recent heartbeat
[2016-07-05 15:24:02,256] {models.py:311} INFO - Failing jobs without heartbeat after 2016-07-05 15:21:47.256816
[2016-07-05 15:24:07,177] {jobs.py:574} INFO - Prioritizing 0 queued jobs
[2016-07-05 15:24:07,182] {jobs.py:726} INFO - Starting 0 scheduler jobs
[2016-07-05 15:24:07,182] {jobs.py:741} INFO - Done queuing tasks, calling the executor's heartbeat
[2016-07-05 15:24:07,182] {jobs.py:744} INFO - Loop took: 0.007725 seconds
[2016-07-05 15:24:07,249] {models.py:305} INFO - Finding 'running' jobs without a recent heartbeat
[2016-07-05 15:24:07,249] {models.py:311} INFO - Failing jobs without heartbeat after 2016-07-05 15:21:52.249706
```

Can somebody guide me over here?

Thanks
Pari

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default every dag that is created is at "pause" mode. This is defined in your "airflow.cfg" file.
You can unpause your dag by

```
$ airflow unpause test-air
```

and retry again with the scheduler.

You can also toggle your dag on/off from the Airflow webUI (by default it is off)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did figure out through WebUI but did not know it is pause/unpause at backend. 

Many Thanks

Comment: @PariksheetBarapatre If this helped you, could you mark it as the correct answer !

Comment: Sorry for delay. Done. 

Do you have any idea re. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38304567/airflow-dag-id-access-in-sub-tasks

Comment: Anyone looking for newer versions of airflow try using
`airflow dags unpause dag_id`.