# AirFlow dag id access in sub-tasks

Tags: oozie, airflow

I have a DAG with three bash tasks which is scheduled to run every day.

I would like to access unique ID of dag instance(may be PID) in all bash scripts.

Is there any way to do this?

I am looking for similar functionality as Oozie where we can access WORKFLOW_ID in workflow xml or java code.

Can somebody point me to documentation of AirFlow on "How to use in-build and custom variables in AirFlow DAG"

Many Thanks
Pari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object's attributes can be accessed with dot notation in jinja2 (see https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#macros). In this case, it would simply be:

```
{{ dag.dag_id }}
```

Answer (score 0):

i made use of the fact that the python object for `dag` prints out the name of the current dag. so i just use jinja2 to change the `dag` name:

```
{{ dag | replace( '<DAG: ', '' ) | replace( '>', '' ) }}
```

bit of a hack, but it works.

therefore,

```
clear_upstream = BashOperator( task_id='clear_upstream',
    trigger_rule='all_failed',
    bash_command="""
      echo airflow clear -t upstream_task -c -d -s {{ ts }} -e {{ ts }} {{ dag | replace( '<DAG: ', '' ) | replace( '>', '' ) }}
    """
)
```