# Airflow scheduler keep on Failing jobs without heartbeat

Tags: scheduler, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-scheduler

I'm new to airflow and i tried to manually trigger a job through UI. When I did that, the scheduler keep on logging that it is `Failing jobs without heartbeat` as follows:

```
[2018-05-28 12:13:48,248] {jobs.py:1662} INFO - Heartbeating the executor
[2018-05-28 12:13:48,250] {jobs.py:1672} INFO - Heartbeating the scheduler
[2018-05-28 12:13:48,259] {jobs.py:368} INFO - Started process (PID=58141) to work on /Users/gkumar6/airflow/dags/tutorial.py
[2018-05-28 12:13:48,264] {jobs.py:1742} INFO - Processing file /Users/gkumar6/airflow/dags/tutorial.py for tasks to queue
[2018-05-28 12:13:48,265] {models.py:189} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /Users/gkumar6/airflow/dags/tutorial.py
[2018-05-28 12:13:48,275] {jobs.py:1754} INFO - DAG(s) ['tutorial'] retrieved from /Users/gkumar6/airflow/dags/tutorial.py
[2018-05-28 12:13:48,298] {models.py:341} INFO - Finding 'running' jobs without a recent heartbeat
[2018-05-28 12:13:48,299] {models.py:345} INFO - Failing jobs without heartbeat after 2018-05-28 06:38:48.299278
[2018-05-28 12:13:48,304] {jobs.py:375} INFO - Processing /Users/gkumar6/airflow/dags/tutorial.py took 0.045 seconds
[2018-05-28 12:13:49,266] {jobs.py:1627} INFO - Heartbeating the process manager
[2018-05-28 12:13:49,267] {dag_processing.py:468} INFO - Processor for /Users/gkumar6/airflow/dags/tutorial.py finished
[2018-05-28 12:13:49,271] {dag_processing.py:537} INFO - Started a process (PID: 58149) to generate tasks for /Users/gkumar6/airflow/dags/tutorial.py
[2018-05-28 12:13:49,272] {jobs.py:1662} INFO - Heartbeating the executor
[2018-05-28 12:13:49,283] {jobs.py:368} INFO - Started process (PID=58149) to work on /Users/gkumar6/airflow/dags/tutorial.py
[2018-05-28 12:13:49,288] {jobs.py:1742} INFO - Processing file /Users/gkumar6/airflow/dags/tutorial.py for tasks to queue
[2018-05-28 12:13:49,289] {models.py:189} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /Users/gkumar6/airflow/dags/tutorial.py
[2018-05-28 12:13:49,300] {jobs.py:1754} INFO - DAG(s) ['tutorial'] retrieved from /Users/gkumar6/airflow/dags/tutorial.py
[2018-05-28 12:13:49,326] {models.py:341} INFO - Finding 'running' jobs without a recent heartbeat
[2018-05-28 12:13:49,327] {models.py:345} INFO - Failing jobs without heartbeat after 2018-05-28 06:38:49.327218
[2018-05-28 12:13:49,332] {jobs.py:375} INFO - Processing /Users/gkumar6/airflow/dags/tutorial.py took 0.049 seconds
[2018-05-28 12:13:50,279] {jobs.py:1627} INFO - Heartbeating the process manager
[2018-05-28 12:13:50,280] {dag_processing.py:468} INFO - Processor for /Users/gkumar6/airflow/dags/tutorial.py finished
[2018-05-28 12:13:50,283] {dag_processing.py:537} INFO - Started a process (PID: 58150) to generate tasks for /Users/gkumar6/airflow/dags/tutorial.py
[2018-05-28 12:13:50,285] {jobs.py:1662} INFO - Heartbeating the executor
[2018-05-28 12:13:50,296] {jobs.py:368} INFO - Started process (PID=58150) to work on /Users/gkumar6/airflow/dags/tutorial.py
[2018-05-28 12:13:50,301] {jobs.py:1742} INFO - Processing file /Users/gkumar6/airflow/dags/tutorial.py for tasks to queue
[2018-05-28 12:13:50,302] {models.py:189} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /Users/gkumar6/airflow/dags/tutorial.py
[2018-05-28 12:13:50,312] {jobs.py:1754} INFO - DAG(s) ['tutorial'] retrieved from /Users/gkumar6/airflow/dags/tutorial.py
[2018-05-28 12:13:50,338] {models.py:341} INFO - Finding 'running' jobs without a recent heartbeat
[2018-05-28 12:13:50,339] {models.py:345} INFO - Failing jobs without heartbeat after 2018-05-28 06:38:50.339147
[2018-05-28 12:13:50,344] {jobs.py:375} INFO - Processing /Users/gkumar6/airflow/dags/tutorial.py took 0.048 seconds
```

And the status of job on UI is stuck at `running`. Is there something i need to configure to solve this issue?

Comment: The line ```INFO - Failing jobs without heartbeat after 2018-05-28 06:38:50.339147``` is just an info message and states what the scheduler is doing, it is not an error message related to your DAG not running. There must be some other reason that your job is hanging.

Comment: I understand that it is not an error message. The problem is that these messages are coming repeatedly.

Comment: Do you know what your scheduler interval is set to in your airflow.cfg file? the scheduler will run every `scheduler_interval` to check for things that need to be scheduled and killed.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200493/scheduling-airfflow-dag-job

Comment: Did you figure out what was causing this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @Mazar, I didn't.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it's not a "Failing jobs" problem but a logging problem. Here's what I found when I tried to fix this problem.

1. **Is this message indicates that there's something wrong that I should
   be concerned?**

   No.

   "Finding 'running' jobs" and "Failing jobs..." are INFO level logs
   generated from `find_zombies` function of heartbeat utility. So there will be logs generated every
   heartbeat interval even if you don't have any failing jobs
   running.
2. **How do I turn it off?**

   The `logging_level` option in `airflow.cfg` does not control the scheduler logging.

   **There's one hard-code in
       `airflow/settings.py`:**

   > `LOGGING_LEVEL = logging.INFO`

   You could change this to:

   > `LOGGING_LEVEL = logging.WARN`

   Then restart the scheduler and the problem will be gone.

Comment: In my case, it is also marking downstream tasks as "upstream failed". Do you know how to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score -1):

I think in point 2 if you just change the logging_level = INFO to WARN in airflow.cfg, you won't get INFO log. you don't need to modify settings.py file.

Comment: Thanks for answering! You could improve your answer by stating what "point 2" is, rather than referring to something not in the question, and by explaining why not needing to modify settings.py is preferable.

Comment: Your solution would simply mask an underlying issue, not solve it.